# jQuery focus() method not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, frameworks

I'm building an Outlook formatter and am having a problem getting the value of the input in the form to display on the copyDiv.  It displays everything in theWholeString except for the inputted values.  I'm thinking something might be wrong with the focus() method.  How can I fix this so that the input is displayed as well?  Here's my source code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
  var lastName = $("#lastName").val();

  var lastNameLC = lastName.toLowerCase();
  var firstInitial = firstName.substr(0, 1);
  var firstInitialLC = firstInitial.toLowerCase();
  var firstInitialLast = firstInitial.concat(lastName);

  var theWholeString = "New-RemoteMailbox -Alias " + firstInitialLast + " -Name " + '"' + firstName + " " + lastName + '"' + " -FirstName " + firstName + " -LastName " + lastName + " -DisplayName " + '"' + firstName + lastName + '"' + " -UserPrincipalName " + firstInitialLC + lastNameLC + "@belmont.gov -RemoteRoutingAddress " + firstInitialLC + lastNameLC + "@belmont.gov.onmicrosoft.com -OnPremisesORganizationalUnit ";

  var finalString = "";

  $("#submitButton").click(function() {

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
      if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        finalString = theWholeString + "blueone.pd/PDUser";
      } else {
        finalString = theWholeString + "belmont.local/BelmontUsers";
      }
    });

    $("#copyDiv").html(finalString).end().appendTo($("body"));
  });

  return false;
});

function changeFocus(id) {
  var v = "#" + id;
  $(v).focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:120px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <h4>1. Enter name:</h4>
        <form id="nameForm" method="post" action="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">First:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Last:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="check-box">
            <label for="policeDept">Police Department?</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="pdCheck" data-group-cls="btn-group-sm">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="submitButton" type="button" value="Submit" />Make </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
          <h4>2. Copy this text:</h4>
          <div id="copyDiv" class="panel panel-default" style="padding:10px">Result
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: F12, what's in the console?

Comment: The `changeFocus` method is never called ?

Comment: Nothing is in the console.  Where should I call it?

Comment: @CamilleDunning When do you want to change the focus?

Comment: You're setting `firstName` and `lastName` when the page is loaded, before the user has entered anything into the input fields.

Comment: And you're not adding the checkbox click handler until AFTER the user clicks on the submit button. So you have to click submit, then check the checkbox, then click submit again.

Comment: It's almost always wrong to add an event handler inside another event handler.

Comment: Why do you think you need to change focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the values from the input fields when the user clicks on the submit button, not when the page is loaded.

And you don't need a click handler for the checkbox, just have the submit function test whether the checkbox is checked.

I can't see any need for the `changeFocus()` function, it doesn't seem to be related to your problem at all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitButton").click(function() {

    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var lastName = $("#lastName").val();

    var lastNameLC = lastName.toLowerCase();
    var firstInitial = firstName.substr(0, 1);
    var firstInitialLC = firstInitial.toLowerCase();
    var firstInitialLast = firstInitial.concat(lastName);

    var finalString;

    var theWholeString = "New-RemoteMailbox -Alias " + firstInitialLast + " -Name " + '"' + firstName + " " + lastName + '"' + " -FirstName " + firstName + " -LastName " + lastName + " -DisplayName " + '"' + firstName + lastName + '"' + " -UserPrincipalName " + firstInitialLC + lastNameLC + "@belmont.gov -RemoteRoutingAddress " + firstInitialLC + lastNameLC + "@belmont.gov.onmicrosoft.com -OnPremisesORganizationalUnit ";
    if ($(':checkbox').is(":checked")) {
      finalString = theWholeString + "blueone.pd/PDUser";
    } else {
      finalString = theWholeString + "belmont.local/BelmontUsers";
    }

    $("#copyDiv").html(finalString).appendTo($("body"));
  });

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:120px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <h4>1. Enter name:</h4>
        <form id="nameForm" method="post" action="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">First:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Last:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="check-box">
            <label for="policeDept">Police Department?</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="pdCheck" data-group-cls="btn-group-sm">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="submitButton" type="button" value="Submit" />Make </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
          <h4>2. Copy this text:</h4>
          <div id="copyDiv" class="panel panel-default" style="padding:10px">Result
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```